# CodeInteger Error Message: Message: Call to undefined function link_tag(

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<title>Login</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
   <?php echo link_tag('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>
    <?php echo link_tag('assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')?>
   <?php echo link_tag('assets/css/form-elements.css')?>
    <?php echo link_tag('assets/ico/favicon.png')?>
   <?php echo link_tag('assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png')?>
   <?php echo link_tag('assets/ico//apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png')?>
   <?php echo link_tag('assets/ico//apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png')?>
    <?php  echo link_tag('assets/ico//apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png')?>
</head>
```

i did not write any Controller or Model class , just to include the above Styles and Images in page , it show the Message: "Message: Call to undefined function link_tag()"Error even i have wrote the following code also in config/autoload file $autoload['helper'] = array('url');"" Error e

Comment: Autoload the url helper and html helper application > config > autoload.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link_tag()` is a function which defined in HTML helper. You should load HTML helper first.

You have 2 options, first one:

Open, `application/config/autoload.php` and add `'html'` value in helper array.

Second one:

Add this line top of your code.

```
$this->load->helper('html');
```

Then, edit your lines like this:

```
    $link = array
          (
           'href' => 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
           'rel' => 'stylesheet',
           'type' => 'text/css',
          );

echo link_tag($link);
```

But I think you can just use `site_url()` function. If you want to use `site_url()`, you should load url helper and edit your lines like below:

```
<link href="<?php echo site_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: i add $this->load->helper('html') ; in autoload .php it change the error into Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$load

Comment: No, it's wrong. Please read carefully what I wrote. If you want to autoload it, you just need to edit `$autoload['helper'] = array();` line to `$autoload['helper'] = array('html');` but as I said, I think you just load url helper instead of html helper and use `<link href="<?php echo site_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` structure.

Answer (score 0):

You using wrong helper. You should add to your autoload 'html'

Please check documentation

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#link_tag

Answer (score 0):

Try using base_url(); instead.

```
 <?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>
```

Comment: Same error Message: Call to undefined function base_url()

Comment: If you want to use base_url() function, you should load URL helper. Also please use site_url() instead of base_url().

Comment: $this->load->helper('url'); add this in your controller.

Comment: But it just echoes "assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" to the page. I explained it with details on my post.

Comment: you loaded the helper in controller..?